# Three-phase, 480 V, 200 A supply, 480 V, 30 A load/charger compatible?

Tags: voltage, power, current, charger, source

I have a 480 V, 30 A charger for a large JLG/lift. The power cord for the unit says it is only rated for 30 A. Could I still use this unit with my 480 V, 200 A source/disconnect? Would I need a breaker or fuse to go down in amps? I know I will need to change the connector, but aside from that, is the wire gauge an issue? Does the unit need to be internally fused to be OSHA compatible?

Comment: If you need to ask these questions (and rely on websites to give good guidance), at the power levels you are talking about and, the likelihood of fire should it be got wrong, you should be consulting an electrician or other expert directly (IMHO).

Comment: Could you clarify what disconnect in "480V 200A source/disconnect" means?

Comment: When you say 30A power cord, this has a plug at the end? Like a NEMA L22-30?

Comment: By all means use this site to get a better idea of what's involved, but doing this wrong is likely to result in you or someone you care about coming down with a mild case of death, so I would strongly recommend handing this off to a qualified electrician.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, all electrical work in commercial must be done by a licensed electrician, and may also require a permit to be pulled from the municipality.

Your 200A service should enter a "service panel" aka "panelboard" or "load center".  An appropriately sized circuit breaker will be installed there. The circuit breaker must be approved for the panel.

You are required to follow the instructions and labeling.

On the charger, that will call out a particular size of breaker.  If it doesn't, follow your local Electrical Codes.

Most likely this will amount to your electrician installing a dedicated *branch circuit* for the charger, and fitting the appropriate wall socket. They can easily use one that matches the plug that is already on it.

Note that fork lift battery chargers do not follow EVSE rules and are not EVSEs.

That said, there can be an issue with compatibility with 480V supplies, depending on how the charger is arranged internally.  If it is designed for 480V "delta" power which does not have neutral, it should work with any 480V supply.  If it needs 480V "wye" which has neutral and 277V from neutral to each phase, then it will only work on buildings provided with that voltage.